# Dexterous Manipulation with Robotic Hand

Tags: control, redundant-robots

I am currently working for my M.Sc. Thesis with the [Allegro Hand](http://wiki.wonikrobotics.com/AllegroHandWiki/index.php/Allegro_Hand) with which I have to perform some simple in-hand manipulation tasks, such as lifting or rolling a cube with 2 or 3 fingers. This has to be done with a model-based impedance control scheme.

I have tried to read similar works but unfortunately I don't have the slightest idea how to begin working on it. Also I cant find a ROS compatible simulator to experiment with the existing ROS packages for the Allegro. Any kind of help on how should I start or how to get it going would be greatly appreciated as I have done zero progress so far.

Comment: Dexterous in-hand manipulation should have a rich research history.  I suggest you ask your advisor to help you find relevant papers.  The best manipulation simulator I know about is [GraspIt!](http://graspit-simulator.github.io/).  But I don't know about ROS drivers for it.

Comment: It does but most of them are learning based approaches and I must missing something on the model-based ones cause I cant seem to understand how to start the controller design process.  Sadly the advisor is not very reachable. I have tried Graspit but so far I failed to import the hand correctly.